# FDM for boundary value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

Given the problem

\begin{align}
&u''− x^2u(u − 1) = 0,\\
&u(1) = 2,\\
&u(3) = 4,
\end{align}

solve it with a finite difference method with the interval divided into $N+1$ equal intervals between $1 \leq x \leq 3$.

- First in detail write the equations when $N=3$.
- Draw the interval and mark the discretization points for the differential equation in the $N$ inner points for arbitrary $N$-value.
- Write the equations $f(u) = 0$. Write a MATLAB function that for a given $u$ calculates $f(u)$.
- Use global values for the boundary values.

What I can do is transform the differential equation to first order:

$
v_1=u,\\
v_2=u',\\
v_2'=u''.
$

Hence

$
v_2'-x^2v_1(v_1-1)=0\\
v_1(1)=2\\
v_1(3)=4
$

But I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Solving a boundary value problem using finite differences requires that you reduce your differential equation to a system of linear equations.

For this particular problem we're solving a differential equation on the interval $[1,3]$ split into $N+1$ equal subintervals. Thus we are looking for a vector $\textbf{u} = [ u(x_{0}),u(x_{1}),\ldots,u(x_{n+1})]$ containing the function values at the points $x_{i} = 1 + i(\frac{2}{n+1})$.

Recall the finite difference formula for the second derivative of a function:
$$ f''(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^{2}}$$

If you let $h$ be the space between successive values $x_{i}$ then the differential equation can be rewritten as the following system of linear equations:
$$ [u_{i+1} - 2u_{i} + u_{i-1}]/h^2 + x_{i}^{2}u_{i}(u_{i} - 1) = 0, \quad 1\leq i \leq n $$
$$ \textrm{and}\quad u_{0} = 2, \quad u_{n+1} = 4.$$
This system is easily solved in MATLAB.

Comment: Many thanks for this good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your first order differential equation is incorrect. Where is the $u_2 ''$?
And why don't you use the finite difference quotient for the second derivative?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated and corrected the question. It should be u2'' like you said and I've now corrected it. And I now remember that for the FDM I use the finite difference quotient but I didn't remember that on top of my head, now I realize that the next step to take is to apporximate the derivatives with difference quotients.